# Receiving data from a server using ESP8266 /Arduino Uno

Tags: automation, arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a Raspberry Pi working as a WiFi hotspot and an Arduino Uno trying to get data from it using an ESP8266 module.

This is my receiver code for Arduino:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SerialESP8266wifi.h>

#define sw_serial_rx_pin 4 //  Connect this pin to TX on the esp8266
#define sw_serial_tx_pin 6 //  Connect this pin to RX on the esp8266
#define esp8266_reset_pin 5 // Connect this pin to CH_PD on the esp8266, not reset. (let reset be unconnected)

SoftwareSerial swSerial(sw_serial_rx_pin, sw_serial_tx_pin);

// the last parameter sets the local echo option for the ESP8266 module..
SerialESP8266wifi wifi(swSerial, swSerial, esp8266_reset_pin, Serial);//adding Serial enabled local echo and wifi debug

String inputString;
boolean stringComplete = false;
unsigned long nextPing = 0;

void setup() {
  inputString.reserve(20);
  swSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
    ;
  Serial.println("Starting wifi");

  wifi.setTransportToTCP();// this is also default
  // wifi.setTransportToUDP();//Will use UDP when connecting to server, default is TCP

  wifi.endSendWithNewline(true); // Will end all transmissions with a newline and carriage return ie println.. default is true
  wifi.begin();
  wifi.connectToAP("RPi", "raspberry");
  wifi.connectToServer("192.168.50.1", "1234");
  wifi.send(SERVER, "ESP8266 test app started");
}

void loop() {
  //Make sure the esp8266 is started..
  if (!wifi.isStarted())
    wifi.begin();

  //Send what you typed in the arduino console to the server
  static char buf[20];
  if (stringComplete) {
    inputString.toCharArray(buf, sizeof buf);
    wifi.send(SERVER, buf);
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }

  //Send a ping once in a while..
  if (millis() > nextPing) {
    wifi.send(SERVER, "Ping ping..");
    nextPing = millis() + 10000;
  }

  //Listen for incoming messages and echo back, will wait until a message is received, or max 6000ms..
  WifiMessage in = wifi.listenForIncomingMessage(6000);
  if (in.hasData) {
    if (in.channel == SERVER)
      Serial.println("Message from the server:");
    else
      Serial.println("Message a local client:");
    Serial.println(in.message);
    //Echo back;
    wifi.send(in.channel, "Echo:", false);
    wifi.send(in.channel, in.message);
    nextPing = millis() + 10000;
  }

  //If you want do disconnect from the server use:
  // wifi.disconnectFromServer();
}

//Listen for serial input from the console
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    inputString += inChar;
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute, the serial monitor shows:

> OK ARFa C⸮C⸮j⸮H⸮AT+AWJAP="RPi",#raspberry" WIFI DISCONNECT WIFI
>   CONNECVED WIFI GOT IP
>
> OK AT+CIFSR
>
> > +CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.50.13"
> >     +CIFQR:STAMAC,"2c:3a:eAT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","192.0n8.50.1",121l
>
> Link type ERROR

Raspberry Pi's ISC DHCP server:

> wlan0: STA 2c:3a:e8:4e:bf:70 RADIUS: starting accounting session
>   5A3B2C85-000000E9 wlan0: STA 2c:3a:e8:4e:bf:70 WPA: pairwise key
>   handshake completed (RSN)

I also referred to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085995/arduino-uno-esp8266-reading-servers-response) with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Some assumptions because you have not given the info:
Arduino IDE >=1.85
ESP8266 Community package >=2.41

ESP Module ESP8266-12E with latest AT firmware

if that is the case and these fragments (enclosed by **X X**) are no typos

> +CIFQR:STAMAC,"2c:3a:e**X**AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","192.0**X**n**X**8.50.1",121l

this leaves the following points to check

- hardware connectors - serial connectors between arduino and esp module
- stable power source 3.3V for the ESP module 
  Sure this is ok - but just in case and as reference for other readers
- serial speed - try to increase from 9600 to 57600 or even to 115200 baud
- These pieces of code should be in the setup() and not in the loop()

> ```
> //Make sure the esp8266 is started..
> if (!wifi.isStarted())
> wifi.begin();
>
> //Send what you typed in the arduino console to the server
> static char buf[20];
> ```

- Code processing

> ```
>  nextPing = millis() + 10000;
> ```

at the end of

> ```
>  if (in.hasData) {
> ```

might lead to interuptions in the communication 
Reason due to the processing of code this might trigger at an unwanted point